# Computing quadrature points on triangle

Tags: equation-solving

According to http://math2.uncc.edu/~shaodeng/TEACHING/math5172/Lectures/Lect_15.PDF page 7, it is possible to compute coordinate of quadrature points by using the script

```
n = 2;
m = 2;
p1 = Tuples[{1, Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i]}, {n}];
p2 = DeleteDuplicates[p1, Times @@ #1 == Times @@ #2 &];
p3 = Times @@ # & /@ p2;
p4 = Integrate[#, {Subscript[x, i], 0, 1}, {Subscript[y, i], 0, 
      1 - Subscript[x, i]}] & /@ p3;
sys = And @@ 
  Table[p4[[j]] == Sum[Subscript[w, i] p3[[j]], {i, 1, m}], {j, 1, 
    6}]
Solve[sys, {Subscript[w, 1], Subscript[w, 2], Subscript[x, 1], 
  Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2]}, Reals]
```

However, Mathematica gives no solution. There is something wrong with the script or am I missing the real meaning? I know that there should be a solution over two points even this is not acceptable.

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: I think you are missing a factor for the RHS sums (1/2). Does your script work for 1D?

Answer (score 3):

The reference provided in the question recommends `m = 3`, so that is what I consider.  (Edit: `m = 2` has no real solution, as can be seen from `NSolve[sys, var]`.)  The equations with minor simplification then become

```
n = 2;
m = 3;
p1 = Tuples[{1, Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i]}, {n}];
p3 = DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ p1];
p4 = Integrate[#, {Subscript[x, i], 0, 1}, {Subscript[y, i], 0, 
            1 - Subscript[x, i]}] & /@ p3;
sys = Table[p4[[j]] == Sum[Subscript[w, i] p3[[j]], {i, 1, m}]/2, {j, 1, 6}] 
var = Flatten@Table[{{Subscript[w, i], Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i]}}, {i, m}]
Solve[sys, var]
```

Also, the right side of the equations in `sys` is divided by two, a minor correction.  As expected, the problem is underdetermined and give a multiplicity of solutions.  To obtain the specific one in the reference, replace the definition of `sys` by

```
sys = Table[p4[[j]] == Sum[Subscript[w, i] p3[[j]], {i, 1, m}]/2, {j, 1, 6}] /. 
    {Subscript[w, 1] -> 1/3, Subscript[w, 3] -> 1/3, 
     Subscript[x, 1] -> 1/6, Subscript[y, 1] -> 1/6}
```

which yields the desired

```
{{Subscript[w, 2] -> 1/3, Subscript[x, 2] -> 1/6, Subscript[y, 2] -> 2/3, 
  Subscript[x, 3] -> 2/3, Subscript[y, 3] -> 1/6}, 
 {Subscript[w, 2] -> 1/3, Subscript[x, 2] -> 2/3, Subscript[y, 2] -> 1/6, 
  Subscript[x, 3] -> 1/6, Subscript[y, 3] -> 2/3}}
```

Comment: Then I misunderstood the reference. "In theory,Ng= 2 may work since in this case we are going to have 6 unknowns... but the resulting quadrature is
NOT symmetric". I explored this possibility thinking real solutions exist... but apparently the reference is not "well" written.

Comment: @Fabio  A better answer (than the one I deleted) to your comment is that the lack of symmetry made me concerned that the roots would not be real, so I tried first `Solve` without `Reals` and, when that returned with no answer, `NSolve` without `Reals`, which gave complex solutions.  Then, I went on to `m = 3`.  I agree that the sentence you quoted is not very informative.